# RE: Update service reference changes web config

Tags: wcf, web-config

When I update my `service references` it modifies the `web config bindings` adding a `default contract` to the config.
I have already specified my own `generic contract` to the `web.config` but every-time I do an `Update Service reference` it automatically changes what I had and places the default binding.

Anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 solutions.

1. Create separate dll that is referencing the service and reference this dll to the main project.

Your main config wont be modified that way.

1. Use config transformation while compiling app.

This transformation would adapt the default configuration to your own needs.

Comment: I also recommend using separate project for service ref.